# Locust Multiple Hosts With Different Peak Concurrency (Web UI)

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance-testing, load-testing, locust

I am trying out the Locust load testing Framework. I have a case where I want to test multiple hosts:

```
from locust import HttpUser, task, between
from tasks import TaskList

class FirstUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(5, 15)
    host = "https://example.com"
    tasks = TaskList

class SecondUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(5, 15)
    host = "https://anotherexample.com"
    tasks = TaskList
```

I have found that Locust accepts a `fixed_count` parameter to spawn an exact number of users on a class.

I want this `fixed_count` to be set from the Web UI. I can see from the Locust source code [here](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/locust/templates/index.html) that it should be possible to pass an `extra_options` to define new fields on the Web UI Form. There is however no documentation on how to define these fields nor how to obtain the values they submit.

Does anyone know how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it could be made more prominent or more clear, but the Locust docs do talk about how to get [custom arguments](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html#custom-arguments) to appear in the web UI using this example:

```
@events.init_command_line_parser.add_listener
def _(parser):
    parser.add_argument("--my-argument", type=str, env_var="LOCUST_MY_ARGUMENT", default="", help="It's working")
    # Set `include_in_web_ui` to False if you want to hide from the web UI
    parser.add_argument("--my-ui-invisible-argument", include_in_web_ui=False, default="I am invisible")
    # Set `is_secret` to True if you want the text input to be password masked in the web UI
    parser.add_argument("--my-ui-password-argument", is_secret=True, default="I am a secret")
```

You then can access your custom arguments in your User like this:

```
class WebsiteUser(HttpUser):
    @task
    def my_task(self):
        print(f"my_argument={self.environment.parsed_options.my_argument}")
        print(f"my_ui_invisible_argument={self.environment.parsed_options.my_ui_invisible_argument}")
```

It should be possible to add a custom argument to the web UI that you can then use to set your `fixed_count` to.

Comment: This is perfect! I misunderstood the docs, I figured a command_line_parser would be, well, for the command line!

I was able to get the `fixed_count` set quite easily using the `on_start` method

`self.fixed_count = self.environment.parsed_options.fixed_count`

Thanks for your help!